# How to update an element value with the duplicated value?

Tags: c#, linq

How to update an element value with the duplicated value?

Let's say I got 4 elements in my list as you can see, there is Dog1 and Dog2 element:

> Name: Dog1 Price: NULL Age: 14 ImportDate = 14.07.2019 15:00
>
> Name: Dog1 Price: NULL Age: 17  ImportDate = 14.07.2019 14:00
>
> Name: Dog1 Price: 14.00 Age = 13 ImportDate = 14.07.2019 13:00
>
> Name: Dog2 Price: NULL Age: 14 ImportDate = 14.07.2019 16:00
>
> Name: Dog2 Price: NULL Age: 17  ImportDate = 14.07.2019 10:00
>
> Name: Dog2 Price: 22.00 Age = 13 ImportDate = 14.07.2019 09:00

Of these elements in the list, I only want to keep the dogs with the newest ImportDate, also I want to keep these two elements from the list:

> Name: Dog1 Price: NULL Age: 14 ImportDate = 14.07.2019 15:00
>
> Name: Dog2 Price: NULL Age: 14 ImportDate = 14.07.2019 16:00

Under I provided a codeline to keep these two dogs in the list and remove the rest.

```
    dogList
      .GroupBy(x => new { 
         x.Name, 
         x.ImportDate.Date 
       })
      .Select(g => g
         .OrderByDescending(x => x.ImportDate)
         .First())
      .ToList();
```

But the two dogs that I'm keeping in the list doesn't have any Price. 
What I want to do is to set the price for these dogs that has value NULL to have the price on the existing dog on a particular date that hasa price, in this case the newest dog1 should have the price 14:00 and dog2 should have the price 22.

How can I achieve this? 
I guess I need to find the element from the list, then find the price for the dog given name and importdate. Then update the element from the list with the settlement

The result should look like this after updating the value in the list:

> Name: Dog1 Price: 14.00 Age: 14 ImportDate = 14.07.2019 15:00
>
> Name: Dog1 Price: 14.00 Age: 17 ImportDate = 14.07.2019 14:00
>
> Name: Dog1 Price: 14.00 Age = 13 ImportDate = 14.07.2019 13:00
>
> Name: Dog2 Price: 22.00 Age: 14 ImportDate = 14.07.2019 16:00
>
> Name: Dog2 Price: 22.00 Age: 17 ImportDate = 14.07.2019 10:00
>
> Name: Dog2 Price: 22.00 Age = 13 ImportDate = 14.07.2019 09:00

And the end result should be a list with these elements :

> Name: Dog1 Price: 14.00 Age: 14 ImportDate = 14.07.2019 15:00
>
> Name: Dog2 Price: 22.00 Age: 14 ImportDate = 14.07.2019 16:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want or can't create new instances you can use this approach:

```
dogList = dogList
    .GroupBy(d => d.Name)
    .Select(dogGroup =>
    {
        Dog latestDog = dogGroup.OrderByDescending(d => d.ImportDate).First();
        if (!latestDog.Price.HasValue)
        {
            latestDog.Price = dogGroup
                .FirstOrDefault(dog => dog.Price.HasValue)?.Price.Value ?? null;
        }
        return latestDog;
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: .FirstOrDefault(dog => dog.Price.HasValue)?.Price.Value ?? null;

What should I do if none of the elements grouped in name and importdate doesn't have  price at all? How can I just set it as null? :)

I'm getting "Sequence contains no matching element" sometimes. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Let's say if I'm going to use this code, should I create a new method for this? Which I pass in a data list and return a new list? :)

Comment: Let's say I have a method that creates and modify all these dogs elements. Before returning I want to perform your code to fix the issue I'm describing, would it make sense to have it in my method or create a new one then call on it?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest *creating* `Dog` instance from each group:

```
var filtered = dogList
  .GroupBy((item => new { 
     item.Name, 
     item.ImportDate.Date 
   })
  .Select(chunk => new Dog() { //TODO: Use the right syntax here
     Name       = chunk.Key.Name,
     ImportDate = chunk.Max(item => item.ImportDate), 
     Age        = chunk
       .Aggregate((s, a) => s.ImportDate < a.ImportDate ? s : a)
       .Age,  
     Price      = chunk.Where(item => item.Price.HasValue).Max(item => item.Price.Value)
   })
  .ToList();
```

**Edit:** The main principle (creating new `Dog` instance) remains the same, by we may want to change some evaluations in the last `Select`:

`Name` - name of the chunk:

```
   Name = chunk.Key.Name
```

`ImportDate` - maximum possible:

```
   ImportDate = chunk.Max(item => item.ImportDate),
```

`Age` - Age corresponding to the `ImportDate`. Here we have to compute `ArgMax`  (or `MaxBy`) which is *not preseneted* in standard *Linq* (implemented in `MoreLinq`); but can be emulate with `Aggregate`

```
     Age = chunk
       .Aggregate((s, a) => s.ImportDate < a.ImportDate ? s : a)
       .Age
```

Finally, `Price` is *not null* highest price:

```
     Price = chunk.Where(item => item.Price.HasValue).Max(item => item.Price.Value)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. @Dmitry Bychenko
Would this update these elements and just pick the newest element to keep in the list of these duplicates based on Importdate.Date?

Comment: I updated the topic, I saw that I was a bit too fast.

Comment: let's say if the dog() type has another property called HairColor. Let's say I also want to keep its original color, that doesn't need to update. Would it work with your code?

Comment: @Ken Kaneki: If `Dog` instances can have some other properties (say, `Color`) you want to preserve, you should either add them into `Select` (which `Color` should be taken from group of several dogs?) or switch to *Tim Schmelter's solution*: extract a `Dog` istance and modify it.